# WPF : Maximize /Restore icons are missing from the Visual Studio Icon gallery. What are the work arounds?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create the Maximize and Restore buttons similar to the visual studio ones. I downloaded the Visual Studio Icon gallery but only minimize icon is available there.

As per this link, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f19c19c8-60f6-4f2d-bfca-2cc365949769/i-cant-find-maximize-icon-in-visual-studio-20152017-image-library?forum=csharpgeneral, those ones are not icons but a font called segoe mdl assets. But this font is only available in Win-10. I am not on Win-10, so what are the options here?

There is no code to share because, I am not sure how this could be done in code.

Comment: It appears that Segoe MDL2 Assets replaced the Segoe UI Symbol font, which will be kept for backwards compatibility. Also, the maximize glyph is a square. You could use a `Rect` or a `Path` or a `Border` to reproduce it scalably.

Comment: @EdPlunkett. Thanks. Could Segoe UI Symbol be used here to create these icons. I looked in Charmap for these shapes but no avail. Just asking, meanwhile testing cyboashu's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple (and bit crude). For Max and restore, pure XAML,  all you need is Boder(s) laid on canvas.

See the code below to get started:

---

Max button :

```
<Button x:Name="CommandMax"
        Width="15"
        Height="15"       
    >
    <Canvas Width="15"
            Height="15">
        <Border
                Width="10"
                Height="10"
                BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="1,3,1,1" />
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

---

Restore Button :

```
<Button x:Name="CommandRes"
        Width="15"
        Height="15" >
    <Canvas Width="15"
            Height="15">
        <Border Background="Gray"
                Width="10"
                Height="10"
                Margin="2,0"
                BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="1,3,1,1" />
        <Border Background="Gray"
                Width="10"
                Height="10"
                Margin="0,5"
                BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="1,3,1,1" />
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

Change height/width,  color and background  for restore etc.. till it fits your application style.